# I can't run Yeoman generator-angular-fullstack in server vps CentOS7

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular, centos7

I have a problem with xdg-open when I try to run "grunt serve:dist" in a Centos 7 VPS with the following message:

> Warning: Command failed: xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://0.0.0.0:9000'

I tried reinstalling the xdg-util but it didn't work.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grunt serve:dist` is not built for serving your site, only a way to preview the dist version in developpment phase.

To serve your project you have to :

- generate the `dist/` folder with `grunt` or `grunt build`
- go to `dist/` then `node server.js`

Comment: In my angular-fullstack I doesn't have dist/server/app.js but I has the file dist/server.js and if I run `node server.js` into the folder dist I can see the following message:
> Express server listening on 0.0.0.0:9000, in development mode
And I tried to access to the url http://[ipserver]:9000 but it didn't work.

Comment: can you run `export NODE_ENV=production` then try again `node dist/server.js` ?

Comment: Does your VPS allow port 9000 from the outside? On AWS, for example, this needs to be allowed explicitly with Security Groups.

Answer (score 0):

`grunt serve:dist` *should* serve up your app just fine via the express:prod task--did you try going to the URL manually? Do you have a default browser installed?

The error message you got was because there is no web browser set up to open the resulting URL. Maybe install Chromium or your preferred browser and try again? There is also a way to specify the open command to use in the grunt-open task runner.

See https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-open for details.

Comment: I tried going to the URL http://[ipserver]:9000 from my notebook but it doesn't load the page. The server has google-chrome installed but I don't know how to set this browser as default in xdg-open. Is possible to know if express is working? any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you running it on your laptop? As the other answer states, serving your site on a production server is not what grunt serve is meant for. You should install the full stack skeleton on your laptop, then publish to the vps. When you say "doesn't load the page" what do you see on screen?